# How to make custom builds for different users with MSBuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a C# project called TestProduct.sln
Unfortunately depending on the user the program 
has to react diffently at one point. How can i tell
the program for which user it is compiled?
Do i have to use DefineConstants while building like:

```
msbuild /p:DefineConstants=USER1 TestProduct.sln
```

and within my code:

```
#if USER1
    // do something USER1 specific
#endif
```

Or do i have to do something completely different to archieve the wanted behavior?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: Sorry for expressing myself wrong, i have to clarify the situation. Users was the wrong wording i had to call it customers. Foreach customer there is a batch file which starts the msbuild command. And within the msbuild command i want to tell built binary for which customer it will be provided.

Comment: You can use $(USERNAME) to read the USERNAME environment variable.

Comment: @Action Heinz, could you get useful information from dude and cristallo's suggestions? I agree with them, use the Environment variable would be a good path for this issue. Not the same issue, but a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690574/is-there-a-way-to-make-user-specific-pre-post-build-events-in-visual-studio-proj

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past and I addressed it in this way.

I get username using the `$(USERNAME)` environment variable.
Then I have multiple batch file named `USERNAME.doit.bat` and in post build event VS runs `$(USERNAME).doit.bat`. In this way each user has its own file batch for the custom post build operations.